# How to join the Pig output files?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

The pig script output a few part files (part-m-00000, part-m-00001, etc) with .pig_header and .pig_schema and I am trying to join them as one output csv. 
I tried to use the hadoop merge

```
hadoop fs -getmerge ./output output.csv
```

but the files are merged with the .pig_schema file as well so it becomes something like

```
header1,header2,header3
{"fields":[{"name": "header1", "type":...}]}
value1,value2,value3
```

How do I join them correctly without the .pig_schema included?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a fileglob: `hadoop fs -getmerge ./output/part* output.csv`

Comment: Thanks! How do I include the header (.pig_header) as well?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but you can probably just add it as an argument: `hadoop fs -getmerge ./output/.pig_header ./output/part* output.csv`